# How to convert qcow2 to VMDK in openstack kilo

Tags: qemu, openstack, vmdk

I was trying to convert qcow2 to vmkd in Openstack Kilo version using the qemu img convert.

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 osname.qcow2 -O vmdk osnamenew.vmdk
```

But the converted image while booting in Vmware compute host, it showing - "no operating system found "(through console in vmware).

Is there any way to to convert it to working vmdk format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tag your image for appropriate devices.
First Find the controller type:

```
head -20 osnamenew.vmdk
output:
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=fc9c51b
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="monolithicSparse"

# Extent description
RW 80325 SPARSE "cirros_ide.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.geometry.cylinders = "79"
ddb.geometry.heads = "16"
ddb.geometry.sectors = "63"
ddb.adapterType = "ide"
```

look at `createType` and  `ddb.adapterType`.
now create the image in glance using provided information:

```
openstack image create   --disk-format vmdk   --container-format bare   --property vmware_adaptertype="ide"   --property vmware_disktype="sparse"   --property hypervisor_type="vmware"   --property vmware_ostype="ubuntu64Guest"   osnamenew < osnamenew.vmdk
```

change the vmware_ostype depending on the image.

Now Launch an instance using the new image.